# The "/etc/init.d/networking restart" fails to update eth0/eth1 at my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, ubuntu

At my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, "/etc/init.d/networking restart" doesn't seem to update eth0/eth1 interfaces.  Network Manager has been turned off in last reboot and "/etc/network/interfaces" has been updated to use static IP at both eth0/eth1 interfaces plus adding static route to each.  However, nothing changes after issues "/etc/init.d/networking restart" or "stop" & "start".

Comment: at this point I recommend `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` for refreshing interface config.

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/init.d/networking restart` command has been disabled in 14.04.

To restart your interfaces you have to use:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup eth0 && sudo ifup eth1
```

I found an explanation for this here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service :

> Restarting networking on a desktop machine will cause dbus and a
>   bunch of service to stop and never be started again, usually leading
>   to the whole system being unusable.
>
> As Ubuntu does event based network bring up, there quite simply isn't
>   a way to undo it all and redo it all, so a restart just isn't plain
>   possible. The recommended way instead is to use ifdown and ifup on the
>   interfaces you actually want to reconfigure

Comment: why disable it?

Comment: I edited my answer with an explanation

Answer (score -1):

Modify the interfaces file and reboot the pc. Don't restart the service because it doesn't always work. Posting the config files also helps us spot any errors.